# How to completely remove the user subsystem from Linux?

Tags: linux, security, users

Is it possible to completely remove the user subsystem from Linux.

I'm NOT talking about preventing people from logging in.  I'm talking about removing the parts of the system that even make it possible to log in.

The outcome being a operating system that once booted cannot ever be accessed because there is no way to access it, apart from applications already running on it (i.e. web server).

The goal being that the system is unhackable through any mechanism that requires gaining user level command line access, because there is no user level command line system present.

Comment: Wouldn't that make everything run as `root`, as implied by @Gravy's answer?

Comment: @andrewhenle the primary goal is to make a system that simply has no mechanism at all for users to run commands on the system and therefore is impossible to get command line access to. If this can be done whilst retaining the concept of users in the system that's fine, but the key thing is I'm talking not ,about disabling things, but deleting entirely the parts of the system that enable login, making it flat out impossible to log in.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can effectively remove shells like `bash`, as much functionality depends on them. That makes preventing "command line access" pretty difficult.

Comment: @drewbenn the goal is a linux system that cannot be logged into, not because it is properly configured to prevent login, rather cannot be logged in to because it is absolutely impossible to log in because the software that facilitates login (and command execution) is not present. So I wonder what needs to be deleted: sshd, shells, login, pam, getty? Is this right, anything else?

Comment: @drew I don't really understand why you need to approve of what I am trying to do. My requirement is a system without code for logging in. With all due respect, that's what my requirement is, why does it need your approval to be valid? What is invalid about my requirement?  You cannot log in to a system without the code to do that - systems that allow you to login but are configured not to, are vulnerable to some unknown hack that will reenable that configuration. I want to remove that possibility.  What further explanation is needed?

Comment: You can't defend entirely against the unknown. Have you covered off command injection via your web application, for example? `nc -l 12345 -e bash -i` (or thereabouts) would allow interactive access but bypassing the login subsystem entirely.

Comment: @roaima the command you propose seems to require bash. Theoretically if I deleted all software that allows users to execute commands then bash would be deleted too?

Comment: And your system then won't boot because much of the initialisation and support utilities are shell scripts. (If they are `dash`, `sh`, of some other shell then adjust my previous comment's code snippet accordingly.) It's an interesting question but I don't think it's one that can be answered in the way you want.

Comment: @roaima yes that makes sense I can see bash is needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting differentiation:

> I'm NOT talking about preventing people from logging in. I'm talking about removing the parts of the system that even make it possible to log in.

I'm not entirely sure there is actually anything other than a semantic difference. If I were to remove `/bin/login` then you would not be able to log in (on the physical terminal) because I had made it impossible to log in. But I would not have removed the entire login subsystem.

My suggestion would be to leave as much intact as possible because there may be unforeseen dependencies. Leave users in place, so that your web server runs as a different account than `root`. Prevent interactive and non-interactive logins by modifying the PAM subsystem. Optionally prevent `sudo` type access in a similar manner.

1. Prepare a "denied" PAM definition

   Create `/etc/pam.d/denied` containing the following two lines:

   ```
   auth requisite pam_deny.so
   session requisite pam_deny.so
   ```
2. Prevent logins from the terminal/screen

   Replace `/etc/pam.d/login` with a copy of `/etc/pam.d/denied`
3. Prevent network logins with `ssh`

   Replace `/etc/pam.d/sshd` with a copy of `/etc/pam.d/denied`

   Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and ensure that `UsePam yes` is set.
4. Optionally, disable at attempt at `sudo`

   Replace `/etc/pam.d/sudo` with a copy of `/etc/pam.d/denied`

Actually, rather than denying all logins, it might be better to permit root logins from the physical terminal/screen and deny everything else. This could also be done via PAM but is outside the specific scope of the question.

Comment: I'm looking to find and snuff out entirely the code that allows logins, whilst still enabling the server applications (like a web server) to run.  I'm m wanting to avoid "configuring things off", I wanting instead to "delete things out".  If sshd existed on the system and if the root user could run commands then the goal has not been met of preventing users ever running commands on the system. sshd would need to be deleted entirely.

Comment: @Duke, mmm, ok. Do you have time to check all the possible interdependencies? I don't. Hence going for the jugular (PAM) and killing that. (Don't delete the PAM files, though, because there are failsafe fall-backs.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, theoretically you could Rename/Delete the `/bin/login` command.

Not sure whether or not that would prevent `single user mode` or not. Also not sure if you are looking to prevent `single user mode` or not.

You could also do some fun things with `pam.d` that would prevent all user logins, but that would be just preventing user logins, not destroying the idea of logins.

When I get home, if i remember, i'll spin up a virtual machine and give it a go. Could also delete the `/etc/shadow` file but that might f up everything else too.

**Side note:** you **do not** want to completely remove the idea of users. Not because not having any login ability is a bad idea(which it is, but thats not the point of this thread), but because due to permissions users need to exist. Without users you would be forced to grant `rwx` on all files on the system in order for your service to run, which would then lead to the problem of not *needing* to login in order to hack things, people could just access whatever they wanted.

Comment: As noted in comment to @andrewhenle, I'm primarily interested in having a system that does not have software on it that enables users to login in and run commands. I'm not so concerned about the concept of users, and as you point out, the concept of users is needed for the system to function.  The question is, what code is it that enables users to login and run commands, and how to delete every scrap of it.